# English term that groups notes and coins of a currency

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms, money

I'm programming a web application and I need to name the "class of things" that are notes and coins.

So far the best I could find was "currency piece".

Is that the correct way of naming the notes and coins of a currency? Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would go with **cash**, which is defined by NOAD as “money in coins or notes, as distinct from checks, money orders, or credit: *the staff were paid in cash | a discount for cash*”

Answer (score -1):

I have been faced with the same dilemma for a day now. I deal with objects that I create in a database in a parent-child relationship.

With this in mind, I have named the table containing this collection

> **currency_denomination_types**

Under currency, the parent, we have *denominations*, which is the various "units of value" that a currency is sub-divided into. Under *denominations* we have the types of denominations.

I realize this is not a one word solution but I believe it will serve the need.